# Overlaying two shapefiles and projecting one of them from Geographic to Projected Coordinate System?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, australia

I am trying to project a shapefile which is in Geographic Coordinate System i.e. Geocentric Datum of Australia 1994 to a Projected coordinate system i.e. Map Grid of Australia Zone 55 using GDA 94 datum, also called as GDA 1994 MGA Zone 55 I think.

I have several shapefiles and this is the only one in a different coordinate system.

I tried to change the projection in Arc Catalog - right clicking the layer going into properties and selecting the projected coordinate system I want but when I actually add the data into ArcMap with other layers already there, I get an error saying:

> Warning, inconsistent extent! One or more of the added layers has an
>   extent that is not consistent with the associated spatial reference
>   information. Re-projecting the data in such a layer may lead to
>   unexpected behaviour

The layer gets added but it doesn't overlap other layers.

Answer (score 1):

When you change the projection via the properties dialog, I don't believe you are re-projecting the data, you are asserting that the data is actually in the projection you are setting it to. That's why it's all screwed up when you try to use it. You need to use the "Project" tool in the Arc Toolbox. It's all explained [here.](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/21447) Even though the article refers to earlier versions of ArcCatalog and Toolbox, it's still valid for 10.2.2

ArcMap does reprojection on-the-fly, so you don't actually need to explicitly convert the data before using it.